# Plot using the axes in an image in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I want to plot over an image using the axes in it. I found a possible way to get a solution with annotations: http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/demo_annotation_box.html

But, is it the easiest way to do it? I have not yet been able to adapt this example to my image.
[Image with axes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLOdn.gif)

Comment: you should first try it, show your code and then ask specific questions

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you mean by "plot over an image using the axes in it". Do you want to have text in the image or a line plot or another image? Please describe es precisely as possible what you expect the result to look like by [edit]ing your question.